# Using mod_rewrite to clean up my navigation uri

Tags: mod-rewrite, uri

I have navigation uris like this

```
/pages/index.php?page=gallery
/pages/index.php?page=users
```

I want to make it so it simply shows the following

```
/Page/Users
/Page/Gallery
```

How can I accomplish this, using mod_rewrite, and can you explain me how it works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: with JS ? let see history function 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API